# Interacting with JavaScript object when web scraping with python and selenium

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web, web-scraping

I am trying to load more comments, which is loaded by clicking on a JavaScript object. Then scrap the page. To test this out, i'm printing the number of comments (inside a p tag) the page contains before and after clicking on the "load more" button. But, it points the same number of p tags before and after. If if you look at the page it has a lot more comments. Where am I going wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='PATH_TO.../phantomjs')
driver.get('http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=1500075')

comments = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
print('Before', len(comments))

time.sleep(1)


try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'loadMore')))
    time.sleep(1)

finally:
    comments = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
    print('After', len(comments))

driver.close()
```

Note that I tried both 'loadMore' and 'loadmoreBlog'.. did not work.
Thanks so much in advance for your answers.

Comment: I don't see where you are clicking the 'load more' element

Comment: If you inspect the load more button on chrome, you can see it. I tried loadmoreBlog as well... that's what shows un in the html source code.

Comment: Should you be waiting on the p tag too? I say this because will the p tags always be there by the time the loadMore tage is present?

Comment: I am not sure. I need to look into it. This is the first time I am using selenium. on the front end, when i click load more button, more contents in p-tags get gets loaded on the page.

Comment: I think I'm not clicking the button. I'm just waiting for something to load... but it doesn't automatically load. I was following an example from the book that uses a page that automatically loads after waiting a certain amount of time

Comment: yup, I needed to add driver.find_element_by_id('loadMore').click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add

```
element.click()
```